# Checksum between 2 files

Tags: hash, checksum

i have 2 files, let's call them "a.exe" and "b.exe" what i want is to have "a.exe" to contain "b.exe"'s checksum and compare it so it knows if "b.exe" was edited, and vice versa.

What i already tried:
My problem is that when i include the checksum on "a.exe" it's checksum changes, same if i include "a.exe"'s checksum on "b.exe".

Is there any workaround to this?

Basically what i want is that both files check each other so if one of them has been changed the other would know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can work, although it's kind of a hack and it's not particularly secure. But depending on your use case, it could be good enough.

First, compile a.exe and b.exe. Then, compute the checksum of a.exe and append it to the end of b.exe. And compute the checksum for b.exe and append it to the end of a.exe.

Now, to have a.exe verify the checksum of b.exe, you do the following in a.exe:

1. Open b.exe as a binary file.
2. Read the contents of b.exe, minus the last few bytes that contain the a.exe checksum, into memory.
3. Compute the checksum of that memory block.
4. Read the checksum for b.exe from the end of a.exe.
5. Compare computed checksum against the value you got from the end of a.exe.

This isn't secure, because somebody could modify the files and change the checksums.

To append the checksum to an exe in Windows:

```
copy /b a.exe + checksum.txt newa.exe
```

I don't know how to do it on other operating systems.

Comment: thank you sir, this might work for what i want to try.